# How to remove Lines thats contain special char after the first :

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

Example:

```
user1@mail.com:password!@#$
user@mail.com:password
user2@mail.com:pa$$w0rd
```

Expected output:

```
user@mail.com:password
```

Comment: What do you tried?

Comment: first i did ".+?(?=\:):+" to get the first part, but im not able to get the part after :

Comment: this looks to work, try it yourself if works in your cases. https://regex101.com/r/6SOQBv/2

If it works, i will post it as answer explaining.

Comment: BTW you should probably never have password lists like that in your app

Comment: @lucas_7_94 this works perfectly, but if a line is "user@mail.com:pa:ssword" , notice the : in password, it will match.

Comment: check now: https://regex101.com/r/6SOQBv/3

Comment: @lucas_7_94 works great now, but not working with grep -oE -a

Comment: how do you know that `!` is not part of the password?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

The details are going to depend on what you mean by "special" chars.
Suppose, just for the sake of discussion, that "special" means non alphabetic and non digit.

Let's run **grep** to look for your "special" pattern: all lines with a colon followed at some point by a "special" char.

```
$ grep ":.*[^A-Za-z0-9]" foo.dat
```

Once you are getting matches on only the lines with your "special" chars you can add grep's **-v** option to omit lines matching your pattern.

```
$ grep -v ":.*[^A-Za-z0-9]" foo.dat
```

In other words, **-v** will only print lines that don't match your pattern, which means in this case it will print lines without a colon followed by a special char.